# Can I detect image request by HTTP headers?

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-headers

Well,
I would like to know if it's possible to detect by HTTP headers if request comes from `<img` tag.

I assume that when request is called from `<img` tag, I'll not have `*/*` header in HTTP_ACCEPT or I'm missing something.

Regards

EDIT:
I've tried with few browser but i can't conclude nothing by HTTP_ACCEPT...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry - a browser request made for an `img` tag will be identical to any other GET request - though as you point out, Firefox does give an `Accept` header specifying that it expects some kind of image but unless all browsers do this it's not very useful.

What's this for? There might be another way to do what you want.

Comment: well... not right... for image (at least for FF) is:
image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

Comment: So it does. I only actually checked Chrome and didn't think Firefox would bother. I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: @confiq: That's not very reliable.

Comment: i need to detect in PHP request if it's image or not. It would be elegant solution using HTTP_ACCEPT...